# {auto_path} linking to category-url instead of page-entry-url?

Tags: category-name, configuration-variables

Is it possible to modify the {auto_path} variable to return the category-url instead of the page-title-url?

for example:

if the search results url, set in channel -> preferences, is:

```
    http://example.com/template/
```

can the {auto_path} return:

```
    http://example.com/template/category/category-url/
```

This is using "exp:search:simple_form". I have the results  displayed in a template using the following:

```
    {exp:search:search_results}  
    <a href="{auto_path}">{title}</a>  
    {/exp.search.search_results}
```

If I use the {path} variable, would the correct format be:

```
    <a href="{path="site_url/template/category(?)/category_url}">{title}</a>
```

How would I get the "/category/" url indicator inserted in the url?

Am I close?

```
    {!--more stuff--}
```

I made a mistake above, which I corrected; the fist segment of the url isn't the channel, it's the template.

I created the site with six template groups - just using the index page for each group; a conditional for "{segment_1}" - the template which selects the channel & "{segment_3}" - the category - which loads sidebar snippets based on the result of the conditional.

The {path} variable should return:

```
    http://example.com/template/category/category-url/
```

Comment: Is this using the Search module? Can you be a little more specific on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

auto_path will always append the URL title:

```
This parameter is replaced with the URL to the entry with the URL Title appended to the end. Unlike other “path” variables, this variable does not require the Template_Group/Template to be specified. Instead, the path will automatically be determined by the Search Results URL setting for the channel in Channel Management.
```

If you want to link somewhere specifically then use the `{path}` variables and follow the template_group/template pattern.

It looks like you're using the Search module but I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to do. If you care to elaborate a little more than I may be able to offer a suggestion if the `{path}` variable doesn't do what you need it to.

Comment: In answer to your edit, why not just use `"{path='template_group/template}/category"`? Where `template_group` and `template` are replace by the actual corresponding names. If you are just trying to add the "/category/" URL indicator without the title to the URL.

Comment: Hi Ian, more edits to the original post…

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to pull back the channel and the category name if one existed.

```
{path="{channel_url}/{categories}{category_url_title}{/categories}/{url_title}"}
```

Comment: Just keep in mind you may see multiple results with this approach. You can add a "limit="1" parameter to prevent that, but can't be guaranteed that the 1 will be the right 1..;)

Comment: Thanks Michael, the new site only has 1 category active at the minute with others coming online shortly. Thanks for the heads up :)